# Create a global keybind in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I have created a simple widget like this:

```
function my_widget() { ... }

zle -N my_widget

bindkey '^P' my_widget
```

The problem is that this keybind does not work all of the time. For instance, when a script is waiting for input via `read` or `vared`, the widget cannot be called. I would like to be able to call it at any time (like `^U` or `^W`).

I have tried adding the keybind to every keymap (except for `.safe`, as it is write-protected).

I want to be able to use my shortcut from anywhere, It does not have to be a ZLE-widget.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: `read` in `zsh` contrary to ksh93 doesn't use the line editor. Use `vared` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I updated the question, I tried both `read` and `vared`. Also I don't always have control over whether other scripts use `read` or `vared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zle`/`bindkey` are to configure the `z`sh `l`ine `e`ditor of the current shell.

The zle is invoked to edit command line in interactive shells or by `vared` to `ed`it `var`iables. In both cases, zle can edit any text, it's not limited to single lines.

`read` doesn't use the line editor, it's to *read* a single line (or other types of records with `-d`) from stdin (or some other line descriptor with `-u`) which don't have to be a terminal device and store the words in that record into the supplied variables.

If you want to let the user enter some text in a script and use zle to edit it, you have to use `vared`. For instance with:

```
var=; vared var
```

instead of `IFS= read -r var`, bearing in mind that the input will always be read from the user on the terminal, even if stdin is not that terminal.

And if you want the line editor of the zsh instance started to interpret that script to have a different key binding from the default, you'd need that zsh instance execute those `zle` and `bindkey` commands to define and bind those widgets.

You could add those to `~/.zshenv` for every `zsh` instance (even those that never interact with the user) to have those widget defined and bound, but note that as that ends up defining a new function, you'd want to pick its name carefully to remove the risk of it conflicting with a command of function used by any of the script you'll ever use.

As for `^W` and `^U`, note that while `zsh` has zle widget for those, they mimic (and enhance) the corresponding *widgets* (`erase` and `kill`) of the terminal device line discipline (in the tty device driver in the kernel) line editor. That line editor (which is used when applications read from the terminal without implementing their own line editor) is very basic, only has a handful of widgets (`kill`, `erase`, `eol`, `eof`...), which you can bind with the `stty` command and is not much more configurable beyond that.